Windows Server 2019 Core unable to run gpupdate
I have Windows Server 2019 on four physical servers joined to a domain. I discovered that I could not run gpresult. Specifically, I run:
gpresult /scope computer /h c:\temp\gpresult.html

Which produces the output:
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

The output file is 1KB and blank when opened in a text editor.
I also tried Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy. Initially, the server didn't recognize the cmdlet. I had to install the GPMC role. If I run this locally from the core server:
Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -ReportType Html -Path c:\temp\gpresult.html

I get an error that says:
Value does not fall within the expected range

I found a Microsoft article from last month that offers a work around:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/agpm-gpresult-not-working
But I find that unacceptable as a solution.
Has anyone else encountered and overcome this?

In server-core I would do like the resolution Microsoft gave, to run the command from a remote computer as to read the report you need the GUI. If your goal is to script an automatic report maybe script from a center place. You can check the RSoP from the GroupPolicy's console from a distant computer with an admin account too.
